# paste 0 to string if int number < 10

Tags: c#, tostring, string.format

I got some `ExcelValues`, the fields are named from 700-751 and 800-851. Now, I want to get the results and store them.

```
for (int countDur = 0; countDur<= 51; countDur++)
{
    string excelFieldMember = $"N7{countDur}";
    string excelFieldNonMember = $"N8{countDur}";
}
```

An exception occurs, when the index `countDur` is less than 10 because the result for `countDur = 0` is not `700`, it is `70` then, and so on.

So I used

```
if(countDur < 10)
```

But I think there is a smarter way to reach this. I know there is a `string.Format()` method and because the fields are int values, I have a `IoString()` method where I can paste a parameter for this.

My question is, what do I have to paste in as a parameter? I can't find it in the C# documentation.

If the value is lower than 10, I want to have a 0 written before the index `countDur` gets pasted.

Comment: Btw, you can't mark multiple answers as the accepted answer, only one (because you've tried to accept three different). Chose the one that works, explains it well, provides links to further reading or shows multiple ways(f.e. C#6 and lower). If multiple have the same level chose the oldest. Instead you can upvote all helpful answers if you have sufficient reputation(i think 50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you are looking for a way to use the `ToString` why not just start the `for` loop from the index you need, instead of from `0`:

```
for (int countDur = 700; countDur <= 751; countDur++)
{
    string excelFieldMember = $"N{countDur}";
    string excelFieldNonMember = $"N{countDur+100}";
}
```

In any case, the use of "magic numbers" is prone to bugs if the fields change. See how you can get the value rather than have it stored hard-coded for the loop. *(Same goes for the `+100` for the non-member fields)*

Comment: @peterHasemann - You are welcome :) Think about what I said with the "magic numbers" :)

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
for (int countDur = 0; countDur<= 51; countDur++)
{
    string excelFieldMember = $"N7{countDur:D2}";
    string excelFieldNonMember = $"N8{countDur:D2}";
}
```

This fills the number with trailing zeros, so that you get `700` instead of `70`.

[MSDN: The Decimal ("D") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#DFormatString)

Comment: @TimSchemelter is the `$` is the new convention now for string format?

Comment: @midtwo: yes, that's the C#6 string interpolation operator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Comment: it's nice, sorry for asking. I asked you since you got the highest repu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it's what you need

```
string excelFieldMember = $"N7{countDur.ToString("D2")}";
string excelFieldNonMember = $"N8{countDur.ToString("D2")}";
```